# WebBrowser .Document methods issue

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I'm trying to make a simple program that goes to a page and clicks on a button. However for some reason when I'd try to call a .GetElementByID on a WebBrowser.Document there would be none available, there's only stuff like Equals, GetHash or what have you. No GetElementByID. So I tried to do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://kdp.amazon.com");

            HtmlDocument doc = (HtmlDocument)webBrowser1.Document;

            doc.GetElementByID("whatever");


        }
```

and I get this error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to class
>   type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'. Instances of types that
>   represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent
>   COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the
>   underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of
>   the interface.

Am I missing a reference or something? All of the tutorials I found on stackoverflow say to call methods on webBrowser.Document that I don't have available.

Comment: Which line gives the error? What type is `webBrowser1`?

Comment: webBrowser1 is a WPF control that I added to the app. The htmldocument doc = (htmldocument) line is causing the problem. Mind you that line shouldn't even be there, I should be able to call .GetElementByID on webbrowser1.Document, I just thought to put the error here as maybe it'll make more clear what's going on

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: What is the exact compile-time type of `webBrowser1`?

Comment: The exception doesn't match the code snippet, it is normally induced by a threading problem.  But the failure mode is clear enough, you cannot access the Document property until the DocumentCompleted event fires.  Move your code to an event handler for that event.

Comment: @HansPassant: This is a type-safety issue, not a threading issue.  It looks like he's taking a WPF WebBrowser's `Document` (a COM `object`) and casting it to the WinForms managed wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the unmanaged WebBrowser ActiveX control instead of the managed wrapper.

Change the control to the managed `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://kdp.amazon.com");

Comment: I've done that before but then when I click the button that starts this sequence, I see that something is happening (cursor waiting animation) but nothing is happening in the control that's supposed to be the browser. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If that's really what you're doing, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: Right, I don't, but I also can't see the page loading in the application window.

Comment: Well, yeah.  Loading a page in one `WebBrowser` won't affect another `WebBrowser`.

Comment: let me rephrase the question then - how do I get both the functionality of system.windows.forms.webbrowser AND have it show up in the webbrowser control window, meaning, I want it to load pages there as I execute commands like clicking on buttons? (The problem described in OP is that said functionality isn't accessible to the control)